# Blur text using CSS and jQuery on hover

Tags: jquery, css

How to make text blured using css class and jquery when hover .

```
<p>Text</p>
```

on hover it should turn blured

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/cx2UR/

## **HTML**

```
<p id="para">Text</p>
```

## **CSS**

```
.blur {
   color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
body{
    font-size:20px;
}
```

## **jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#para').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass('blur');
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('blur');
    });
});
```

## **Or Using CSS Only**

```
p:hover
{
color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: We have `:hover` in CSS :D

Answer (score 5):

If you want a pure CSS solution than you can spoof it using CSS `text-shadow`

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2EKd/)</kbd>

```
p:hover {
   color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

Here, I've used `rgba` where `a` stands for *alpha*, which is nothing but opacity... and if you want to smooth up the effect on hover, use CSS `transition` property.

```
p {
    -webkit-transition: all .5s;
    transition: all .5s;
}

p:hover {
   color: transparent;
   text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

<kbd>[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/f2EKd/1/)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

What about a real CSS blur. Works only on webkit browsers but its the real deal. If not supported you can go with a fallback as the ones provided by Mr. Alien and Palash Mondal

```
var blur;

if ('-webkit-filter' in document.body.style) {
    blur = 'filter';    
} else {
    blur = 'shadow';
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#text').hover(function(){
        $(this).addClass(blur);
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).removeClass(blur);
    });
});
```

Edited the code to add a fallback if CSS filters are not supported. Its not triggered by jQuery hover (not my first choice) and fallsback to Mr. Alien text shadow.

**http://jsfiddle.net/buvMF/2/**